# Getting oracle sqlplus select count value into dos batch file

Tags: batch-file, sqlplus, dos

I've got a DOS batch file running an SQLplus select to get a count of rows where a particular column value is 10. This is working fine and I've sucessfully output the value to a file however I'm now having real problems using that value in the batch file. The problem seems to be due to it being a right justified 10 character string.

so if my value is 0 i get this,

```
         0
```

or if my value is 7000 I would get this,

```
      7000
```

What I really want is this,

```
0
```

or this

```
7000
```

Im reasonably sure that If I had the data starting in column 1 then I could use the following to read the data,

```
for %%a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\BBWin\ext\status10.LST") do if /I %%a GTR 300 echo %%a >> "C:\Program Files (x86)\BBWin\ext\status10.txt"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the spaces by doing the following

```
set str=%str: =%
echo."%str%"
```

Where str is the variable containing the value with spaces.

More info [here](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php#Snippets.RemoveSpaces)

Answer (score 1):

The galuano1 answer certainly strips spaces from a value, it should not be required in your case.

The default token delimiters for FOR /F are space and tab. So the leading spaces will be trimmed for you. The value does not have to be left justified :-)

You need to use FOR /F with the USEBACKQ option to read a file with spaces in the name.

```
for /f "usebackq" %%a in ("C:\Program Files (x86)\BBWin\ext\status10.LST") do ...
```

But you don't even need a file! You can directly process the results of your sqlplus using FOR /F by enclosing the command in single quotes.

```
for /f %%a in ('sqlplus ...') do ...
```

You should carefully read the help documentation for the FOR command: type `HELP FOR` or `FOR /?` from the command line. There are many subtle differences in how FOR can be used.

You might also check out this [excellent FOR loop tutorial](http://judago.webs.com/batchforloops.htm)